# Devemos usar pipes em vez de condição ternária no template para renderizar algo no Angular?

Tags: angular

Estou avaliando a melhor abordagem para renderizar algo no meu template a partir de uma condição, de forma que evite renderizações e chamadas de funções desnecessárias pra melhoria do desempenho da aplicação.

Percebi que se eu tenho uma função no meu template para verificar e retornar algo, sempre que há alguma ação na tela, essas funções são chamadas novamente. Exemplo:

```
<div *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
   <h3> {{getUserRole (usuario.id)}} </h3>
</div>
```

E no meu **TS**:

```
getUserRole (id: number) {
   if (id === 0) {
      return 'Professor'
   } else if (id === 1) {
      return 'Estudante'
   }
}
```

Sempre que eu executar uma ação em minha página, por exemplo, um clique em um botão, essa função será chamada, mesmo que desnecessariamente. Uma alternativa para evitar isso é usar `pure pipes`.

Estou me perguntando se, quando eu uso a condição ternária no meu template, isso também ocorre, ou seja:

```
<div *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios">
   <h3> {{usuario.id === 0? 'Professor': 'Estudo'}} </h3>
</div>
```

Se isso também ocorre, quando eu preciso usar `pipes`? Em todos os casos que eu preciso renderizar algo sobre um condicional como nos exemplos acima ou apenas se minha condição for muito pesada (uma matriz com muitos objetos e propriedades)?

Answer (score 1):

Na real eu usaria o pipes só se eu quiser filtrar a lista de usuárias que vai ser exibida.

Veja, no seu caso independente se o usuário é professor ou aluno, vai ser criado uma linha e será exibido.

Agora se você quisesse fazer esse mesmo *ngFor exibir a partir da lista de usuários apenas linhas de professores você poderia fazer isso com um pipe.

No HTML

```
 <div *ngFor="let usuario of usuarios | removerAlunosPipe ">
  ...
 </div>
```

No Ts

```
@Pipe({name: 'removerAlunosPipe', pure: true})
export class RemoverAlunosPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(usuarios: any[]): string[] {
    return usuarios.filter(usuario => usuario.id === 0))
  }
}
```

Lembre que vc precisa importar o Pipe no app.module
Usando um pipe pure true ele vai ser executado apenas quando a variavel usuarios sofrer alteração.